# Vowel counting code issues

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting this program to work, can someone take a look at it and give me a clue on what to do? Thanks!

> Design and implement an application that reads a string  from the user, then determines and prints how many of each lowercase vowel (a, e, i, o, and u) appear in the entire string . Have a separate counter for each vowel. Also count and print the number of nonvowel characters .
>
> SPECIFICATION OF PROMPTS, LABELS AND OUTPUT : Your code should use the prompt "enter string : ". After the input is read, there are six lines of output , each starting with a different label: "a: ", "e: ", "i: ", "o: ", "u: ", "other: " in that order. After each label is the required count.
>
> For example: if "aardvark heebie jeebies" were read in, the output  would be:

```
a: 3
e: 6
i: 2
o: 0
u: 0
other: 12
```

---

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class VowelAnalyst{


    public static void main(String args []){

    int a =0, e = 0, x = 0;
    int u = 0, o = 0, other = 0;
    String text;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("enter string: ");
    text = scan.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);

    if (c=='a')
    a++; 

    else if( c=='e')
    e++;

    else if(c=='i')
    x++;

    else if(c=='o')
    o++;

    else if (c=='u')
    u++;        

    else
    other++;
    }

    System.out.println("a: " + a + "\n" +
    "e: " + e + "\n" +
    "i: " + x + "\n" +
    "o: " + o + "\n" +
    "u: " + u + "\n" +
    "other: " + other);

    }
    }
```

Comment: `if(c=='i') x++; ` ? Other than that, what's the problem with your code (hint : don't just say it doesn't work) ?

Comment: i is initialized in the for loop. It gave me an error so I used x instead.

Comment: `if (c != 'a' && 'e' && 'i' && 'o'&& 'u' )` is invalid. You could use a switch as first solution, or even `if else if else if ... else`.

Comment: OP, I won't make an answer. I'd suggest you write this answer and accept it.

Comment: Users with less then 10 rep cant answer their own questions for 8 hours after asking.

Comment: @terribleCoder: braces are your friend in Java: even though you *can* leave it off from single-statement `if` blocks, it is accident prone, and harder to grok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct except for this part:

```
else if (c != 'a' && 'e' && 'i' && 'o'&& 'u' )
```

It should be written like this:

```
else if (c != 'a' && c != 'e' && c != 'i' && c != 'o' && c != 'u')
```

You could make the code more clear by turning every `if` you have, except the first one, into an `else if`, and the last `else if`, where you check to see if the character isn't any of the vowels, can be simply an `else`:

```
if (c == 'a')
{
    a++;
}
else if (c == 'e')
{
    e++;
}
else if (c == 'i')
{
    x++;
}
else if (c == 'o')
{
    o++;
}
else if (c == 'u')
{
    u++;
}
else
{
    other++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your sequence of `if` statements is invalid. A meaningful rendition would be something like

```
if (c == 'a') a++;
else if (c == 'e') e++;
...
else other ++;
```

However, an even better choice would be to use a switch statement, like so

```
switch (c) {
    case 'a': 
        a++; 
        break;
    case 'e': 
        e++;
        break;
    case 'o': 
        o++;
        break;
    case 'u': 
        u++;
        break;
    default: 
        other++;
        break;
}
```

After fixing that, we need look at what you're missing: all uppercase vowels are currently counted as `other`. We could double up on the conditionals

```
if (c == 'a' || c == 'A')
...
```

or

```
case 'A':
case 'a':
...
```

But there's an easier way: convert the string to lowercase before the comparison.

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char c = Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i));
    switch (c) {
    ...
```

Comment: `+1` - actually, IMO *this* should be the accepted answer, due to pointing out both `switch` & `.toLowerCase()` "tricks".

Comment: IIRC, I hoisted my own petard by up-voting another answer shortly after posting. C'est la vie de stack-overflow.

Comment: BTW, in cases when I want to undo the vote for whatever reason, I usually just edit the answer with any trivial improvement, and then I can revert the vote due to content change... however "shady" may it seem, it works perfectly.

Comment: Wow. Nice tip. I don't mind up-voting a well-written (competing) answer out of courtesy, but timing is key... And I'm not sure even reverting would work quickly enough...

Answer (score 2):

I'll do for each char

```
switch (c)
{
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        a++;
        break;
    case 'e':
    case 'E':
        e++;
        break;
    case 'i':
    case 'I':
        i++;
        break;
    case 'o':
    case 'O':
        o++;
        break;
    case 'u':
    case 'U':
        u++;
        break;
    default:
        other++;
        break;
}
```

It simply counts every vowel and consonants.

Comment: You don't break after the O character. Which means O would also count as a U.

Comment: Also, the assignment is to count lowercase vowels only, not uppercase.